# App doesnt run rake commands when deployed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite3-ruby

in my development are the app works fine but when i deploy to heroku and try to run rake db:migrate to build the database, it aborts and says wrong number of arguments. i have searched all over the web but could not fix it.
here is the error

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ blooming-dusk-86753... up, run.9621 (Free)
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:7:in `add_modifier'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/type.rb:22:in `add_modifier'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:827:in `<class:PostgreSQLAdapter>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:69:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:584:in `get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:318:in `get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:354:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:354:in `add_mapping'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
/app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `eval_block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:373:in `draw'
/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.7', '>= 5.0.7.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13', group: [:development, :test]

# Use postgresql as the database for production
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
#use bootsrtap for styles
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
#use font awesom for icons
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.15.1'
#use devise for user logins
gem 'devise'
#use paperclip for images upload
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

i think the problem is related to sqlite3 vs postgresql(heroku) but i cant seem to fix it.
here is the github link:
https://github.com/fawzi-saab/S-Portfolio

Answer (score 0):

if you are especially creating apps to deploy heroku its better to use postgresql in both development and production. I look into your repo and i think your `config/database.yml` file needs to be revised in order to connect to postgresql database. You can also check a documentation to deploy an app to heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6)

Comment: do you mean the config/database.yml?! i tried to replace the adapter to postgresql and installed the gem . same problem when pushed to heroku. i think the problem might be with the rake command. cause any rake command i try gives the same error. i tried to run rake routes on heroku server and it gave same error!!!

Comment: another thing. when i first tried to push it to heroku it gave the same error and push failed. it gave the error when it tried to run rake on assets pipeline precompile. i ran the assets precompile command locally it worked. then i pushed the app to heroku it went through( here it didnt run the rake precompile asses cause it was defined locally).  this is why im saying that there is something related to rake!